# How do I bringToFront a subview when I touch it?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a rotating carousel menu made up of 6 UIViews that were added as subViews to self.view. When you rotate the carousel, some subviews are partially behind the subview closest to the user but the problem is that the subview closest to the user may not have been added after the one behind it so when I touch it, the one behind it gets triggered.

My question is, is there a way to programmatically use bringToFront whenever a subview is touched so that it will not matter whether or not it was added first or last to the view.

Answer (score 0):

When you have 2 views responding to touch events and one is in front of the other, the other one will never receive the touch.
Instead of messing around with the event chain (aka subclassing UIView and overriding hitTest…) I'd suggest you reorder the views while spinning the carousel.

The view which appears to be in front should be the topmost view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks danielkbx that's exactly what I want to do but I'm not sure how to reorder the views when the carousel is spinning. Right now I have it coded as:    trackingTouch = [touches anyObject];
        
        if (view1 == trackingTouch.view) {
            
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:view1];
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:view2];